# Excel formula, Mapping dates to a bucket

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to map dates to a number

So if a date lands between these months in (photo2) column A then formula will assign whats in the 2nd column, and anything above these numbers will be assigned "6".

I am trying to use `Vlookup` but not sure how to as the dates wont be exact.

My 'Data Mapping Table':

| Mapping Dates | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 11/30/2021 | 1 |
| 12/31/2021 | 2 |
| 01/31/2022 | 2 |
| 02/28/2022 | 3 |
| 03/31/2022 | 3 |
| 04/30/2022 | 3 |
| 05/31/2022 | 4 |
| 06/30/2022 | 4 |
| 07/31/2022 | 4 |
| 08/31/2022 | 5 |
| 09/30/2022 | 5 |
| 10/31/2022 | 5 |

Sample Dates and Output sought:
|Sample Dates|Data|
|--------|--------|
|11/02/2021|1|
|11/30/2021|1|
|12/01/2021|2|
|12/06/2021|2|
|12/15/2021|2|
|12/17/2021|2|
|12/31/2021|2|
|12/31/2021|2|
|12/31/2021|2|
|12/31/2021|2|
|01/11/2022|2|
|01/12/2022|2|
|01/13/2022|2|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track and with `VLOOKUP` and an Exact match.
You just need to convert the sample dates to end of month dates for the match to work.
Excel function for that is `EOMONTH`:

```
=VLOOKUP(EOMONTH(D2,0),$A$2:$B$13,2)
```

The above is as it would appear cell E2, if the tables were like this:
[image]

**Dealing with any date that is 'out of range'**
The above covers all cases where the **Sample Dates** are within in the range of the **Mapping Dates**.
To cater for 'Out of Range' conditions, and alternate approach is required:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(EOMONTH(D2,0),$A$1:$A$13,0)),VLOOKUP(EOMONTH(D2,0),$A$1:$B$13,2),"Out of range")
```

The above is as it would appear cell E2, if the tables were like this:
[image]

The above first tests that the End of Month date exists in the Mapping table date using `ISNUMBER` with `MATCH` (exact).
a)  If so: It does the same as the previous approach (using `VLOOKUP`)
b) If not: It returns the string `Out of range`
You can of course change the `Out of range` return values to whatever you like.

**Dealing with specific dates being 'out of range'**
Lastly: If you want to just treat specific dates as out of range (per you 'greater than Oct 2026' comment), this will do it:

```
=IF(D2>DATEVALUE("31 Oct 2026"),8,VLOOKUP(EOMONTH(D2,0),$A$1:$B$13,2))
```

Notes
a) I'm using date format (`dd mmm yyyy`) to avoid any confusion or issues arising out of system local date format.
b) You can of course change the `out of range` return (currently `8`) to whatever you like.

Comment: cant seem to get this to work , what is EOM? TRying this `=VLOOKUP(EOMONTH((F2),0),Sheet1!D:E,2,FALSE)`

Comment: Yeah, I have a UDF that's EOM (and I forgot that was one of mine). See edited solution above (now correct).

Comment: does the columns got to be a format? Still getting N/A

Comment: As posted, that works. The image is snapshot of a actual worksheet with the formula in action. For it to work as is, the dates must be dates. Sought value could be anything. If the dates in your system are textual (not dates per se), the formula needs a tweak. Are they?

Comment: their dates.. not sure whats wrong!

Comment: Nor am I. Can I ask: Did you copy and paste my formula as is from above?

Comment: thanks! it works! however I need something if date is greater then oct 2026 then return "8"

Comment: Tried something like this `=IF(F964<"10/31/2026",VLOOKUP(EOMONTH(F964,0),Sheet1!D:E,2),"9")` but it wont work!

Comment: Added two alternate solutions for that.